# How can i disable drag event using jquery?

Tags: jquery, draggable

i wan to disable drag event using jquery and want to bind one another event with same mouse event, but it will shows an error

i have attached drag even to

```
<div class="mydiv"></div>
```

and i have used

```
jQuery('.mydiv').draggable("destroy");
```

it is disabling the drag event and attached one more functionality on mouse down

but when i will press mouse on div and dragging the cursor then it shows error

```
$(this).data("draggable") is undefined
[Break on this error] var t = $('body'), o = $(this).data('draggable').options;
```

and this is in ui.draggable.js,

any buddy have any idea about this??

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem might be that you have initialized draggable on a collection of elements, and destroying it on the single element causes some weirdness. What you might try doing is removing the **ui-draggable** class from that particular element:

```
jQuery('.mydiv').removeClass("ui-draggable");
```

Of course, that might not change a thing.

Comment: i have also disable dragging on all dom elements..but it was not working

Comment: This doesn't work. Wish it did. I can't use the regular disable either because of css effects.